# How to convert datetime to time format

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, sql-server-2012

I have a query that returns datetime format in sql:

```
SELECT time_in  
FROM job_punch_card  
WHERE emp_key=47 and punch_day<= DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(day, 0, getdate())/7, 0)
```

This returns results like `2014-2-15 07:36:32.000`, however I only want the time portion, not the dates. I can get the current time from SQL Server like:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),GETDATE(),108) AS HourMinuteSecond
```

But I couldn't apply this to my own query. How can I retrieve only time from `time_in` table above?

Comment: replace `Getdate()` with `time_in` . `SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),time_in  ,108)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the same `CONVERT` function on your output column:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), time_in, 108) AS time_in  
FROM job_punch_card  
WHERE emp_key=47 and punch_day<= DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(day, 0, getdate())/7, 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `CAST` if you need it as a `TIME` type. If you have to do any calculations on the result set this will make things easier.

```
SELECT CAST(time_in AS TIME(0)) AS time_in
FROM job_punch_card
etc., etc.
```

Comment: Looks like OP needs `HH:MM:SS`. But this is going result with Milliseconds

Comment: True, and good catch! I was trying to avoid the `CONVERT` function because I've never liked the arbitrary-looking numeric values like 108 at the end - I find them unreadable. I could add some code to truncate the time, but that'll make the answer way too complicated. Much as I dislike it, `CONVERT` is the way to go here :) I'll delete this answer shortly.

Comment: You could use `CAST(time_in AS TIME(0))` which will give HH:MM:SS

Comment: Thanks @mheptinstall, I realized that right after I hit "Add Comment" :) I'll update my answer... oops, looks like NoDisplayName took care of that. Thanks both for improving the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Almost exactly same manner:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), time_in, 108)
FROM job_punch_card  
WHERE 
    emp_key=47 and 
    punch_day<= DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(day, 0, getdate())/7, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),time_in,108) AS time_in_time_only
FROM job_punch_card  
WHERE emp_key=47 
    and punch_day<= DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(day, 0, getdate())/7, 0)
```

Or:

```
SELECT CAST(time_in AS TIME) AS time_in_time_only
FROM job_punch_card  
WHERE emp_key=47 
    and punch_day<= DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(day, 0, getdate())/7, 0)
```

The latter has the advantage being the time data type instead of a character string, which may be important to what you're doing.

Comment: Looks like OP needs `HH:MM:SS`. But your second query is going result with Milliseconds

Comment: @NoDisplayName Then use `TIME(0)` instead of `TIME`, or handle it in the application which is what should be responsible for formatting anyways.  Returning a data type of time is good for that.  The poster didn't specify directly that they did or didn't want milliseconds, just that they wanted to be able to extract the time.

Comment: OP needs the result as like `convert(.. ,108)` which will not include Milliseconds